# fetching single word title using $split and $size using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.movies.aggregate(
 [ {$project:{_id:0,oneword_title:{$split:["$title"," "]}}}, 
   {$unwind:"$oneword_title"} 
]);
```

I am splitting my title in to substrings to fetch single words title and now how should i retrieve title with only single word.

Comment: Please see [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your OP so we can try and help :-)

Comment: db.movies.aggregate([
{$project:{oneword_title:{$split:["$title"," "]},_id:0}},
{$project:{leng:{$size:"$oneword_title"},oneword_title:1}},
{$match:{leng:{$eq:1}}}
])

Comment: I tried the above and it worked thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to make it more succinct:

```
db.movies.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
              oneword_title: {$split: ["$title", " "]}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
               "oneword_title": {$size: 1}
            }
        },
    ]
).itcount();
```